# How to use xsl number to count elements with the group

Tags: xslt

I am going to count proceduralStep in order as below. I am not sure how to implement.

XML:

```
<mainProcedure>
    <proceduralStepAlts>
        <proceduralStep/>
        <proceduralStep/>
    </proceduralStepAlts>
    <proceduralStep/>
    <proceduralStepAlts>
        <proceduralStep>
            <proceduralStepAlts>
                <proceduralStep/>
                <proceduralStep/>
            </proceduralStepAlts>
        </proceduralStep>
        <proceduralStep/>
    </proceduralStepAlts>
</mainProcedure>
```

Valid to Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="mainProcedure" type="mainProcedureElemType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="mainProcedureElemType">
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="proceduralStep"/>
            <xs:element ref="proceduralStepAlts"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="proceduralStep" type="proceduralStepElemType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="proceduralStepElemType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="title"/>
            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:element ref="proceduralStep"/>
                <xs:element ref="proceduralStepAlts"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="proceduralStepAlts" type="proceduralStepAltsElemType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="proceduralStepAltsElemType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="proceduralStep"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Desired Oupput:
        1
        1
        2
        3
        3.1
        3.1
        3.2
        3
        4

Why desired output: proceduralStepAlts wrapping multiple procedural Steps, the set is considered to be only “one”, and thus each procedural Step is displayed with the same outline number.

Comment: Can you explain why the output should be `1 1 2 3 3` ? What is the logic in assigning these numbers? This ins't clear at all from the question.

Comment: The output is because proceduralStepAlts wrapping multiple procedural Steps, the set is considered to be only “one”, and thus each procedural Step is displayed with the same outline number.

Comment: user2268666, As per your explanation, my answer does exactly that. Is my answer useful to you, or do you still have any problems?

Answer (score 0):

This stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="proceduralStepAlts">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="proceduralStep[parent::proceduralStepAlts]">
        <xsl:value-of select="
                count(parent::proceduralStepAlts/preceding-sibling::proceduralStepAlts)
              + count(parent::proceduralStepAlts/preceding-sibling::proceduralStep)
              + 1"/>                
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="proceduralStep[parent::mainProcedure]">
        <xsl:value-of select="
              count(preceding-sibling::proceduralStepAlts)
            + count(preceding-sibling::proceduralStep)
            + 1"/>                
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces your desired output with the provided input.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="proceduralStepAlts/proceduralStep">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "concat(count(../preceding-sibling::*) +1, ' ')"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/proceduralStep">
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "concat(count(preceding-sibling::*) +1, ' ')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<mainProcedure>
    <proceduralStepAlts>
        <proceduralStep/>
        <proceduralStep/>
    </proceduralStepAlts>
    <proceduralStep/>
    <proceduralStepAlts>
        <proceduralStep/>
        <proceduralStep/>
    </proceduralStepAlts>
</mainProcedure>
```

**produces the wanted result:**

```
1 1 2 3 3
```

---

**Second Solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*[self::proceduralStep or proceduralStep]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="proceduralStep | proceduralStepAlts">
  <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>

  <xsl:for-each select="self::proceduralStep | proceduralStep">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat($vPos, ' ')"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced**:

```
1 1 2 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just counting the elements below the root element, so you could use this expression

```
<xsl:number count="/*/*" />
```

Here is the 'full' XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text"/>

   <xsl:template match="proceduralStep">
      <xsl:number count="/*/*" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output:

```
11233
```